# How to read the content of an website?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, urllib

I'm new on web-crawler using python 2.7.

#### 1. Background

Now, I want to collect useful data from [AQICN.org](http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/) which is a great website offering the air quality data all over the world.

I want to use python to get all China's sites data per hour. But I'm stuck right now.

#### 2. My trouble

Take this website(http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/) for example.

This page offer the air pollution and meteorology parameters of a U.S Consulate in China. Using code like this, I can't get useful information.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

html_aqi =    
urllib.urlopen("http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/json").read().decode('utf-8')
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_aqi)
l = soup.p.get_text() 
aqi= json.loads(l)
```

The result shows like this:

```
> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

So, I change the html_aqi to this format(reference to someone's work):

http://aqicn.org/aqicn/json/android/shenyang/usconsulate/json

The code works well.

#### 3. My target.

*format 1: ([http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/json)](http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/json)_)*
*format 2: ([http://aqicn.org/aqicn/json/android/shenyang/usconsulate/json)](http://aqicn.org/aqicn/json/android/shenyang/usconsulate/json)_)*

In general, I can deal with the format 2 . But, I have collected websites of all sites in China which in format 1. 
So, can anyone offer me some help to cope with format 1? Thanks a lot.

#### Update

format 1 is hard to transformed into the second format(Lots of conditions need to be considered.)

It can't be done easily using code like this:

```
city_name = url_format1.split("/")[5]
site_name = url_format1.split("/")[6]
url_format2 = "http://aqicn.org/aqicn/json/android/"+ city_name + "/"+    site_name

### --- Reason Why it's hard  in practice  
1559 sites need to be care with, and these sites differ by their location.     
Some are in city, some are in county. Their url are not the same pattern.   
for example: 
Type1 --> http://aqicn.org/city/hebi/json
Type2 --> http://aqicn.org/city/jiangsu/huaian/json
Type3 --> http://aqicn.org/city/china/xinzhou/jiyin/json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in the Air Quality Index number, find the `div` with `aqivalue` class:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> url = "http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/json"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url), "html.parser")
>>> soup.find("div", class_="aqivalue").get_text()
u'171'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply so quick! I tried it. And it works. By the way, how to list all the class the website can offer? I want to get more div(For example, so2, temperature, wind, etc). Typing `soup`, the content were too heavy.

Comment: @HanZhengzu usual approach would be to inspect the desired elements using the *browser developer tools*. Note that it does not always mean you will find the element in the HTML the `urllib` got you since there are many things happening in the browser to construct the page - additional API calls, javascript code execution etc - `urllib` is not a browser. Just take that into account in the future. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your guide! I'm now using _Chorme Developer Tools_ hoping to find my interest content.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. For the contents like this " Values are converted to the US EPA AQI standard."></td><td id="min_pm10" class="tdmin" style="color:#0086c8;font-size:11px;" align="center">53</td>" which I clipped from the html documents. How to get the value 53. I tried your method, but failed.

Comment: @HanZhengzu how about `soup.find("td", id="min_pm10").get_text()`?

Answer (score 2):

The first url http://aqicn.org/city/shenyang/usconsulate/json actually does not give back JSON data. It gives back HTML data. If you're really interested in this content, you have to parse the HTML data.

You can do this with [Beautifulsoup's HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), though the [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) package is somewhat more straightforward.